# Selenium - tuple object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem with test selenium - page object pattern. My code:

```
class FormPage(Page):
    nameConnect = (By.ID, "name")

    def nameUser(self,name):
        names = self.driver.find_element(*FormPage.nameConnect)
        names.send_keys(name)

class testUser(Page):

    start_page = FormPage(self.driver)
    start_page.nameUser('user22xx')
```

**my error:**

```
start_page.nameUser('user22xx')
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

How I can change my code? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error says "nameForm", but I can't find this anywhere in your code? Is this a typo?

Comment: nameUser ;) not form

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you ran? Check that there are no parentheses behind `*FormPage.nameConnect`

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace from the exception? You're using a construct I am not sure is legal syntax.